# Copy from filename and insert into file

Tags: php, regex, match, sh

i have a folder of different files, but all files contain brackets with different words in it.
e.g.: From-The-(Far)-East.html and From-The-(near)-West.html

Is it possible to copy the content of the brackets into the file with a special tag between the "body"-tag and to remove the brackets after the insert?
e.g.: From-The-(Far)-East.html -> copying "Far" and insert it with this tag `<test>brackets=Far</test>` into the file between `<body>...</body>`? -> after that the file name should be From-The--East.html (and this for multiple files)

I thought it is possible with some regex to match/copy the content of the brackets, then insert it with some "fopen" and then rename the file. Would be nice, if someone could help me a bit. (Maybe someone knows how to manage that with a shell script)

Thank You

Comment: show the content of such a file

Comment: https://pastebin.com/q0Xx7XJH
it's a sample file that shows the raw structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one?

```
$di = new DirectoryIterator($inputpath);
foreach ($di as $file) {
    if ($file->isFile() && $file->isReadable()) {
        $namePart = '';
        if (preg_match('/\((.*)\)/', $file->getFilename(), $namePart) === false) {
            continue;
        }

        $content = file_get_contents($file->getPathname());
        $content = str_replace('<body>', '<body><test>' . $namePart[1] . '</test>', $content);
        file_put_contents($file->getPathname(), $content);

        $newFilename = str_replace($namePart[0], '', $file->getPathname());
        rename($file->getPathname(), $newFilename);
    }
}
```

It goes through all files in `$inputpath`
If the file is a file and readable it tries a match via regex. The result in `$namePart` should be equal to `['(Far)', 'Far']` (given your example).

Then it inserts the name into the file. I know I've used a dumb function; but it does what you requested.

After inserting the string into the file it changes the file's name.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with gawk (on linux)

Create a file named 'rename.awk':

```
x==1{ print "<test>brackets=" b "</test>" >newFilename; x=0 }
NR==1 { split(FILENAME,a,/[()]/); b=a[2];  newFilename = a[0] a[1] a[3] a[4] }
/<body/{ x=1 }
{ print $0 >newFilename }
```

$ gawk -f rename.awk "From-The-(Far)-East.html"

After this you should have this:

```
$ cat "From-The--East.html"
<html>
<head>
<title>From-The-(Far)-East.html</title>
</head>
<body>
<test>brackets=Far</test>
From-The-(Far)-East.html
</body>
</html>
```

(At least if the original file looked like this:

```
$ cat "From-The-(Far)-East.html"
<html>
<head>
<title>From-The-(Far)-East.html</title>
</head>
<body>
From-The-(Far)-East.html
</body>
</html>
```